# Selective routing with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I have some queues bound to one topic exchange, e.g. with routing keys:

```
1) big.yellow.rabbit
2) small.*.dog
3) small.*.*
4) *.*.cat
5) *.*.*
```

I want the RabbitMQ to choose **only one** queue to place my message by following logic:

- the number of coincident tags should be as big as possible
- coincidence of first tag is more importat than for second...

Examples for aforementioned keys:

```
big.yellow.rabbit -> 1) 
small.yellow.rabbit -> 3) 
small.white.cat -> 3)
big.grey.cat -> 4)
big.yellow.pig -> 5)
```

I've come to conclusion that common exchange types (direct, topic, fanout, headers) will not help me. And I need to implement new custom type.
Am I right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the routing logic you describe is not implemented by any of the default exchange types in RabbitMQ; you'll have to write your own.

You'll need to [write](http://www.rabbitmq.com/plugin-development.html) a RabbitMQ [plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/plugins.html).  More concretely, you'll need to write a *custom exchange type*: you can find a bunch of examples on the [Developer Tools](http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html) page.

If you need any pointers on how to get started or get stuck, post a question on the [RabbitMQ-Discuss](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/rabbitmq-discuss) mailing list.  The RabbitMQ developers read that list and make a point of not leaving any questions unanswered.